# Is there a way to automatically store integers in an ArrayList using a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

My main goal is to get an array that consists of the place values of a number.
for example: if the user input is: 35779 
I want this array: {3, 5, 7, 7, 9} 
(the user input might change and it can range from 10 to the max possible value of an int.

(int counter is an int that represent how many place values does the input number has. example: when input is: 38557: counter = 5)

```
    ArrayList<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = counter-1; i >= 0 ; --i){
        int ten2pow = (int)Math.pow(10, i);
        int x = input/ten2pow;
        obj.add(x);
        input = input - x*ten2pow;
    }
```

when doing this and trying to print the array, the output is an empty array

Edit: after changing the for loop initialization and termination condition, the loop worked just fine, and I was able to store the Place values in the ArrayList

Comment: What is `5 <= 1`?

Comment: Is `counter` given? Or do you need to calculate it?

Comment: If he does need to calculate it, he's doing it wrong.  Better to start with the least significant digit, and keep dividing by ten until nothing is left.

Comment: Try using this in the condition for(int i = counter -1; i >= 0 ; i--)

Comment: Personally I'd probably just let it be handled by regex:  `int[] components = Arrays.stream(Integer.toString(value).split("(?=\\d)")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the condition I was using was wrong 
i edit it to be :
`for(int i = counter-1; i >= 0 ; --i){
}`
and it worked fine

Comment: @Frakcool the number of place values (counter)  is calculated using a while loop:
  `while (placeValue != 0){
   placeValue = placeValue/10;
   counter++;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess the number is given, if it need to be read from console, then I'm leaving that part out.

Suppose our number is: `35779`, then a simple way to "divide" it, digit by digit might be:

1. Get module 10 result of `number`
2. Divide `number` by 10

Example:

- Modulus: 9
- `number`: 3577

Repeat:

- Modulus: 7
- `number`: 357

So, this can be done this way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NumbersToArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int number = 35779;

        while (number > 0) {
            list.add(0, number % 10);

            number /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
[3, 5, 7, 7, 9]
```

So, there's no need to get the length of the `number`

Answer (score 0):

As hinted to by Sotirios Delimanolis in the comments on the question, the first issue here is that the for-loop condition is wrong. `i <= 1` will never be true if `i` starts at a number greater than `1`. Also, if the statement were ever to be true (i.e., `i` is `0` or less than `0`), then the increment expression (`i--`) would run until it underflows to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Alnitak also mentions in the comments that it would be better to start with the least significant digit. This follows the [div/mod algorithm for base conversion](http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html), which is more conventional.

The div/mod algorithm for base conversion works by recursively taking *a* modulo *b*, where, *a* is the result of the last modulo operation (starting with the source value) and *b* is the base to convert to. Each iteration provides another digit for the resulting number by its remainder, starting from the right.

Take for example converting 1000 to base 2:

- `1000 % 2 = 500, R 0  =>  ?? ???? ???0`
- `500  % 2 = 250, R 0  =>  ?? ???? ??00`
- `250  % 2 = 125, R 0  =>  ?? ???? ?000`
- `125  % 2 = 62,  R 1  =>  ?? ???? 1000`
- `62   % 2 = 31,  R 0  =>  ?? ???0 1000`
- `31   % 2 = 15,  R 1  =>  ?? ??10 1000`
- `15   % 2 = 7,   R 1  =>  ?? ?110 1000`
- `7    % 2 = 3,   R 1  =>  ?? 1110 1000`
- `3    % 2 = 1,   R 1  =>  ?1 1110 1000`
- `1    % 2 = 0,   R 1  =>  11 1110 1000`

You can see how the remainders are used to determine the resulting value. The code to use this algorithm here would look something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int iteratedValue = input;
do {
    int currentDigit = iteratedValue % 10;
    numberList.add(currentDigit);        
    iteratedValue /= 10;
} while (iteratedValue > 0);

Collections.reverse(numberList);
```

A `do...while` loop is used to ensure that the first digit gets added to the list, even if it is `0`.

A deque or other collection could be used to add the items in reverse as an alternative to reversing the list at the end.